# How to completely clean a whiteboard without harsh chemicals?

Tags: cleaning

I have an older whiteboard that I want to clean up. You're supposed to use only the expo dry erase markers (or whatever the whiteboard markers are), but my silly siblings have used permanent markers on the board. I can get that, and other junk off, with a harsh expo whiteboard cleaner. However, that stuff smells awful and is difficult to apply to an whiteboard hanging off a wall. It just runs off! What I am wondering is: How can I clean my whiteboard without harsh chemicals? Thanks in advance!